# Defining $X=\{hxh^{-1} : h \in G\}$ as a conjugate set. We say that a group $G$ acts over $X$ if

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

$$
f\colon\begin{array}[t]{ >{\displaystyle}r >{{}}c<{{}}  >{\displaystyle}l } 
          G\times X &\to& X \\ 
          (g, hxh^{-1}) &\mapsto& f(g, hxh^{-1})=ghxh^{-1}g^{-1} 
\end{array}
$$
Prove that  this action is transitive.

My answer: An action is transitive when there is $x \in X$ such that the $G-\text{orbit}$ of x in G, that is, $O_{G}(x)=\{(gh)x(gh)^{-1}:g, h \in G\}= X = \{hxh^{-1}, h \in G\}$.

But I am not entirely convinced that my answer is right ....
How do I disappear with the $g$ on the right and on the left in the $G-\text{orbit}$ of x in G set?

Only then, I will make sure that these sets are really the same.

Comment: yes!! Sorry, I forgot to type down.

Comment: Your equation is correct because $\{ gh : g,h \in G \} = G$.

Comment: It's noteworthy that $X$ you're defining to be the conjugacy class ("conjugate set" is not a term used) of a particular element $x\in G$. This seems to have been lost in the edits. It's relevant because then it makes sense why an arbitrary element of $X$ is referred to as $hxh^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x'=gxg^{-1}\in X$. Then this is equal to $f(g,x)$. Since this describes all elements of $X$, we are done: given any $x'\in X$, there exists some $g\in G$ such that $f(g,x)=x'$.

If you only know that $hxh^{-1}\in X$ for some $h$, note that $f(h^{-1},hxh^{-1})=x$, so $x\in X$ and we can use the argument above. Combining, we have that
$$f(gh^{-1},hxh^{-1})=gxg^{-1}$$

Comment: Sorry, I still struggling. Look I know that $hxh^{-1} \in X$. But, how can I make sure that $(gh)x(gh)^{-1}$ is in $X$? Can you explain step by step like for someone just beggining in this topic.

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova If $h$ is also fixed, see the second paragraph I just added.

Comment: Ok, ok, LOL, now I really understood!!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova Sure, no problem.